# Print multiple formated strings with a conditional statement in C

Tags: c, string-formatting, conditional-operator

Is there any way to print multiple strings in C based on only one condition for example

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  printf("%s %s\n", condition ? "string1","string2" : "string3","string4");

  return 0;
}
```

if the condition is true then I would like to have

```
string1 string2
```

as the output but when I do it this way, it is not what I get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need:

```
printf("%s %s\n", condition ? "string1" : "string3", condition ? "string2" : "string4");
```

Comment: I did it that way but, I wanted to know if I could avoid having to repeat the condition

Comment: @Parco No, because of the comma's between the strings.

Comment: @Parco You can always just use an if statement and it might even be clearer

Comment: I could have also used a switch statement since the condition works with enum types but the goal was to avoid that. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @Parco If there are multiple conditions, maybe you could use an array of (pointers to) strings, and then use `arrStrings[enumValue]` for example.